# Certain libraries force Visual Studio to compile F# project every single time

Tags: visual-studio, f#, logary

Certain nuget libraries seem to force my project to rebuild (as in run fsc.exe to produce a new binary) every single time I build the solution, even if nothing at all has changed. As soon as I delete the reference in the Visual Studio references tree, fsc.exe is no longer called until I actually make a change.

I don't actually need any code at all to reproduce this problem - an empty main function in a project referencing a problematic library will face this issue.

After some trial and error two nuget libraries which definitely cause this problem are:

- FSharp.Actor-logary
- Newtonsoft.Json.FSharp

but it may well apply to others.

I read in a comment elsewhere on stack overflow that type providers always force recompiles, is that true? My empty test project doesn't use type providers, but maybe these libraries do.

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've solved it: the problematic libraries have a last modified date of 15/12/2030

I've opened an issue on the project's GitHub page: https://github.com/logary/logary/issues/74

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved when MSFT fixed their assembly-generation bug in mono.